# POST request table Python3

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a table of https://www.domeinquarantaine.nl/, however, for some reason, it does not give a response of the table

```
#The parameters
baseURL = "https://www.domeinquarantaine.nl/tabel.php"
PARAMS = {"qdate": "2019-04-21", "pagina": "2", "order": "karakter"}
DATA = {"qdate=2019-04-21&pagina=3&order="}
HEADERS = {"Host": "www.domeinquarantaine.nl",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Referer": "https://www.domeinquarantaine.nl/",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
"Content-Length": "41",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Cookie": "_ga=GA1.2.1612813080.1548179877; PHPSESSID=5694f8e2e4f0b10e53ec2b54310c02cb; _gid=GA1.2.1715527396.1555747200"}

#POST request
r = requests.post(baseURL, headers = HEADERS, data = PARAMS)

#Checking the response
r.text
```

The response consists of strange tokens and question marks

So my question is why it is returning this response? And how to fix it to eventually end up with the scraped table?

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add data then you can't get it with requests. It can't run JavaScript. You can use Selenium to control web browser which will load page and run JavaScript. Or you have to check all requests from page to server to find ulr which is used by JavaScript to get data.

Comment: open web browser, turn off JavaScript and you will see what `requests` can get.

Comment: using DevTools in Chrome/Firefox you should see POST request to url `https://www.domeinquarantaine.nl/tabel.php` and it sends back HTML with table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of reasons why you're getting what you're getting:

1. Your headers don't look correct
2. The data that you are sending contains some extra variables
3. The website requires cookies in order to display the table

This can be easily fixed by changing the `data` and `headers` variables and adding `requests.session()` to your code *(which will automatically collect and inject cookies)*

All in all your code should look like this:

```
import requests

session = requests.session()
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0", "Accept": "*/*", "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", "Referer": "https://www.domeinquarantaine.nl/", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", "DNT": "1", "Connection": "close"}
data={"qdate": "2019-04-20"}

session.get("https://www.domeinquarantaine.nl", headers=headers)
r = session.post("https://www.domeinquarantaine.nl/tabel.php", headers=headers, data=data)

r.text
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What makes you say that cookies are required to view the table? The table is displayed just fine with @furas answer, which doesn't include a session.

Comment: @glhr I've tried removing the cookies from my code and it doesn't seem to work :)

Comment: If you take OP's code and simply change `"Accept-Encoding"` (in the header) to `"deflate"` or `"utf-8"`, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Open web browser, turn off JavaScript and you will see what `requests` can get.

But using `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox (tab `Network`, filter `XHR` requests) you should see POST request to url https://www.domeinquarantaine.nl/tabel.php and it sends back HTML with table.

If you open this url in browser then you see table - so you can get it event with GET  but using POST you probably can filter data.

---

After writing this explanation I saw you already has this url in code - you didn't mention it in description.

You have different problem - you set

```
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"
```

so server sends compressed response and you should uncompress it.

Or use

```
"Accept-Encoding": "deflate"
```

and server will send uncompressed data and you will see HTML with table